# In a separable normed space, does any set contains a countable dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a separable normed space and $ A \subseteq X$ be nonempty. Does there exists a countable subset $A’$ of $A$ such that $A’$ is dense on $A$? If not, please provide a counterexample. What about the case on which $X$ is finite dimensional?

It seems simple but I have not being able to came up with a general construction, even in finite dimensions. Initially I thought of taking the smallest subspace containing $A$ and defining $A’: = S \cap ric(A)$, where $S$ is a countable dense subset of $X$ and $ric(A)$ denotes the relative interior of $A$, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know an example of a non-separable normed space?  (non-separable = does not have a countable dense subset.) Then just take $A$ the whole space.  For the finite-dimensional case, first prove the whole space is separable (i.e. has a countable dense subset).

Comment: @GEdgar, I edited the question: we assume separability from the begining. It was my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any separable metrisable space is second-countable. Second-countability is hereditary and implies separability. So every subset of a separable metrisable space is separable.

Suppose $S$ is a countable dense subset of $X$. For each $s \in S$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ choose, **if possible**, $a_{sn} \in A$ with $||s - a_{sn}|| < 1/n$. The set of these $a_{sn}$s is a countable dense subset of $A$.

Comment: @Joe Yes, we must assume separability, I edited in the question. Thanks

Comment: Could you please show a specific construction? It would be better for the intuition.

Comment: I've added a direct construction.